# Strange artifact around texture brush

Tags: texture-painting

Trying to paint glowing cracks inside a rocky mesh, but the emission also lights up these strange artifacts which the brush leaves around it.  Even the "erase alpha" brush cannot remove them.  Im really not sure what to do.[image]

Comment: maybe try to increase the Bleed value in the brush options (N panel > Tool > Options > Blee)?

Comment: Cant see any change with changing these values back and forth :(

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your image? https://pasteall.org/blend/